# Как укоротить метод? с#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, checkbox

Как можно укоротить этот метод?
В зависимости от входящего значения он отмечает чекбоксы.

```
private void CheckB(int i)
    {
        switch (i)
        {
            case 0:
                c1.Checked = true;
                return;
            case 1:
                c2.Checked = true;
                return;
            case 2:
                c3.Checked = true;
                return;
            case 3:
                c4.Checked = true;
                return;
            case 4:
                c5.Checked = true;
                return;
            case 5:
                c6.Checked = true;
                return;
            case 6:
                c7.Checked = true;
                return;
            case 7:
                c8.Checked = true;
                return;
            case 8:
                c9.Checked = true;
                return;
            case 9:
                c10.Checked = true;
                return;
            case 10:
                c11.Checked = true;
                return;
            case 11:
                c12.Checked = true;
                return;
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно поместить чекбоксы в массив:

```
private readonly CheckBox[] checkBoxes;
```

В конструкторе (после `InitializeComponent();`) создаем массив:

```
checkBoxes = new[] { c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, c9, c10, c11, c12 };
```

Тогда ваш метод будет выглядеть так:

```
private void CheckB(int i)
{
    if (i >= 0 && i < checkBoxes.Length)
        checkBoxes[i].Checked = true;
}
```

Comment: Вроде видел, что это "семейство" решений называется табличным методом

Comment: Только массив немного не так делать надо... Ведь до вызова `InitializeComponents()` там будут всюду `null`.

Comment: @PavelMayorov я массив сделал в самом методе

Comment: @RomanKravets не лучшее решение - готов поспорить, такой массив вам понадобиться в нескольких методах :) Лучше сделайте его полем как предложено - а заполняйте в конструкторе.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Спасибо, сделаю =)

Comment: @PavelMayorov Действительно, спасибо. Обновил ответ.

Comment: Тем более, если у вас куча чекбоксов, имеет смысл все их прямо и класть в массив, а не выделять каждому по полю.

Comment: @VladD если чекбоксы "накидывались" в форму визуально - то без поля ссылку на них получить не так-то и просто.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: А, ну это да. Но ведь если чекбоксов реально много, никто ж не будет все их старательно добавлять через визуальный редактор, а напишет цикл в две строчки, правильно?

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать через Dictionary. Возможно так быстрее будет.

```
private readonly Dictionary<int, CheckBox> checkBoxes = checkBoxes = new Dictionary<int, CheckBox>(){ {0, c1}, {1, c2}, ..., {11, c12}};

private void CheckB(int i)
{
    CheckBox box;
    checkBoxes.TryGetValue(i, out box);
    box.Checked = true;
}
```